# Link broken up into two?

Tags: python

```
website = "http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/"+word+"/m0u/"
        print(website)
```

The "word" is from a text file containing a list of Japanese words. Instead of printing the full link it prints the part after word "/m0u/" on the line below. For example:

```
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/種類
/m0u/
```

Comment: If it's from a text file, are you sure you didn't get a line break mixed in there somewhere? What if you do `... + word.strip() + ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read lines from a file it includes the newline at the end of the line.

You need to strip it off.

```
with open(word_file) as words:
    for line in words:
        word = line.strip()
        website = "http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/"+word+"/m0u/"
        print(website)
```